"Mixture, Pitch then Power" - why?
The above saying is taught as the process for initiating a climb when flying an aircraft with a constant-speed propeller (and the opposite order for a descent). Why is it the case?
I was originally taught a vague explanation saying that low RPM and high manifold pressure could lead to detonation, but how?
I believe the need to enrichen the mixture prior to a climb is purely for engine cooling purposes, not anything to do with the stoichiometric ratio, please correct me if this is wrong.

This is mostly about when going balls to the wall, but is generally applied to more gentle power applications as well to make it an automatic SOP, and just to go easy on the equipment. Also it's not end of the world on a non-boosted engine to violate it, but it might be on a boosted one.
At max power, you need a full rich mixture both for cooling and detonation margin purposes. It's also good to go to high RPM before manifold pressure because detonation margins are in part a function of Brake Mean Effective Pressure in the cylinder and raising manifold pressure suddenly without speeding up the air pump (engine) tends to spike BMEP.
On a normally aspirated engine, violating these rules won't blow it up (not on an engine running 100 octane and a compression ratio of 8:1 - in car world that would be easy street), but on a turbocharged or supercharged engine the risk is significant and it's good to be consistent with technique as well as just going easy on the machinery.
A secondary factor is if you go to wide open throttle and follow with max RPM too quickly, the governor won't be able to keep up if the change was large and the torque level is maxed out, and the prop will overspeed momentarily as the governor overshoots (everybody on the ground will know about your sin by the YEOOOOOWWWRRR sound).
Anyway, if you're going to climb at maximum power at lower altitude, you do need to go full rich, mostly for cooling but if you are just going from some econ cruise setting like 20" and 2100 RPM to, say 24/square to climb, I might just enrich a little to maintain the EGT and not go full rich.
